# Update QTextDocument's size

Tags: c++, qt, size, qtextdocument

I have a problem with QTextDocument::size()

The size of the document is updated every time user enters something to TextEdit manually. (So in SIGNAL **textChanged** it works fine). However, I insert some text by code.

```
textEdit->insertPlainText("blablablabla\n");
```

When I use this:

```
int iHeight = textEdit->document()->size().height();
```

The iHeight is always equal to 21, even though the textEdit has multiple lines of text. When I use the same line of code in the SIGNAL i talked about, the iHeight magically turns into the correct number.

So basically, my question is how to update the document's size so it returns proper number?

Comment: Calling `setPlainText()` triggers the signal / slot behavior for me (Qt 5.5).  Could you post your code?

Comment: That might be the point. In one case it did trigger the signal, but I've already used Gombat's solution. However, the problem is that **setPlainText()** triggers it, whereas **insertPlainText()** doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the QDocuments width to the width of the QTextEdit to let it know whether there are line breaks. Afterwards it returns the right size.

Example:

```
QTextEdit textEdit;
textEdit.setMaximumWidth(50);
textEdit.setText("Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test");
textEdit.document()->adjustSize();
QSizeF size1 = textEdit.document()->size();
textEdit.document()->setTextWidth(textEdit.width());
QSizeF sizew = textEdit.document()->size();
textEdit.show();
```

Indeed, adjustSize is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `_text->document()->adjustSize();` after inserting the plain text then you can get the proper height.

Comment: Tried it, it decreases document's width massively.

Comment: You can always place the textEdit inside of any type of layout you prefer. Or for instance setFixedWidth(). But it is not related to the correct height.